# How to make urlpatterns in case of "http//domain/include/Tom+Sam/exclude/Bob+Jane"

Tags: python, django

I have tried below:

```
url(r'^include/(?P<in>\w+([+]w+)*)/exclude/(?P<ex>\w+([+]w+)*)/$', views.MW_Tag_Search.as_view(), name='tagSearch')
```

I got Page Not Found.

what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that you have missed out the backslash before the w both times you use `([+]w+)`.

The second problem is that `in` is a keyword in Python, so it's best to avoid using it as a kwarg. I would use `include` and `exclude` instead. Remember to update your view as well!

Try the following:

```
url(r'^include/(?P<include>\w+([+]\w+)*)/exclude/(?P<exclude>\w+([+]\w+)*)/$', views.MW_Tag_Search.as_view(), name='tagSearch')
```